# I need to set value to number from another React JS class

Tags: reactjs

```js
export const Map = {
    list: { name: 'search', number: 123456 }
};
```

What does this code mean?

I need to set value to number from another JavaScript class. help me out on this

Comment: Well, if you have this code just look at where you got it from. For us it is very hard to tell because the context is missing!

Comment: Please add the code as well that u tried till now

Comment: This piece of code alone is present in the js 
class export const Map= {
list:{name:'search',number:123456}
};

Comment: Map.list.push(number:789012); This was my try, but getting refernce error:number is not defined

Comment: This has nothing to do with react, you are missing some basical JavaScript knowledge I fear.
Also **do not use Map** as a name

Comment: You mean - you need to modify the value of Map.list.number ?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ReactJs.

The constant Map is exported from this module(say 'myModule'). So from another module, you can import the Map as follows

```
import {Map} from 'myModule';
```

or as

```
import * as constants from 'myModule';
// then, constants.Map is the value exported from the above module
```

Note this is the new ES2015 syntax. For this syntax to work in legacy environments, you need to use babel to transpile the code into an older syntax.